# How to combine separating columns in each row?

Tags: python, csv, tokenize

I cleaned my csv file which contains 50000 lines of text and tokenized each line. However on each line, words are split up into separate columns:

> 202MAY || DEFEATED || LORDS || PEERS || BACK || NEW || LEVESON

But i want each row to be concatenated rather than separated by each tokenized word:

> 202MAY  DEFEATED  LORDS  PEERS  BACK  NEW  LEVESON

All in one column in each row

Each row has differing amount of words so  differing amount of columns, how would i be able to solve this issue?

Comment: Can we see what you have already? Post a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "202MAY || DEFEATED || LORDS || PEERS || BACK || NEW || LEVESON"

print str.replace(' ||', '')
```

Comment: The '||' arent in the file, I just used them to better visualise the csv file. Each word is in a separate column in the row but i want them to be in one column like a sentence. There is also another 50000 rows that i want to iterate through and merge the columns together in each of those rows. The number of columns per row is undefined, some rows have 5 columns others have 10.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this?

```
some_text = "202MAY || DEFEATED || LORDS || PEERS || BACK || NEW || LEVESON".split("||")

print("".join(some_text))
#expected output:
#202MAY  DEFEATED  LORDS  PEERS  BACK  NEW  LEVESON
```

Comment: Yes that is the desired output, however the '||' characters are not in the csv file, I used them to visualise the CSV file where it is differentiating a new column in the row. There is also 50000 rows i want to iterate through, where each row has an undefined amount of columns (some have 5, some have 10, some have 3), I would like to merge them into one sentence in each row.

Comment: so you want single column in your dataframe which consists of an enitre row?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Yes, I want one column in each row where the tokenized words are merged rather than separated as shown above

Comment: @AdamDavies your csv has same number of columns, right? coz sentence could be any arbitary length.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar Sadly nope, the number of columns on each row differs

Comment: @AdamDavies Have you tried to use regex to get just the alphanumeric values from your data?  '[^\w-]', If this will not help, try to create dummy data that will be like yours and give the clear explanation of what kind of output you want than I think we can solve problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import re
    text = "202MAY||DEFEATED||LORDS||PEERS||BACK||NEW||LEVESON"
    combined_text = re.sub(r"\|\|", " ", text)
    print(combined_text)
```

There are several ways you can do that. The above code uses regular expression to replace '||' with a space(" "). The output will be: 202MAY DEFEATED LORDS PEERS BACK NEW LEVESON.

Answer (score 0):

```
[gokul@python ~]$ cat sample.csv
a,b,c
dd,gg,f,t,y
x,y
[gokul@python ~]$ sed -i "s/,//g" sample.csv
[gokul@python ~]$ cat sample.csv
abc
ddggfty
xy
[gokul@python ~]$
```

so instead of reading the file as structured content,
Just read the file as plain text file and replace commas with null.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. Corrected:-)